# padding for <a> inside <li> pushes through the top of edge of <li>

Tags: css, padding

I have this code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>my link 1</a></li>
   <li><a>my link 2</a></li>
   <li><a>my link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I apply padding to `<a>` like so:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0 0 2.6em;
}
ul li {
  height: 41px;
  width: 196px;
  background: url(images/image.png) no-repeat; 
  position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

The padding works but it collapses and goes through the top edge of `<li>` instead of pushing the `<a>` down. How ca I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried using margin-top: 5px; instead?  This sounds more like what you would want anyway.

Comment: Can you show all the css for that section of code?

Comment: Yup I tried it, didn't work either. But that isn't what I need because it won't fill out the whole area of `li`  to be clickable. Even tried wrapping `li` and `a` with borders.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you should give your "a" display:inline-block

anchors are "inline" by default and won't show padding properly.

jsFiddler demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PqajF/3/

Comment: @jilseego: Thanks don't work. You have to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li a
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit a

See http://jsfiddle.net/nPXyN/

```
<span>padding</span>
<ul id="paded">
    <li><a>my link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>my link 2</a></li>
    <li><a>my link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<span>margin</span>
<ul id="margined">
    <li><a>my link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>my link 2</a></li>
    <li><a>my link 3</a></li>
</ul>



ul#paded li {
    padding-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul#margined li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```